# Finding a closed mathematical form for a parametrized function series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, functions, summation

I am dealing with the following parametrized function series defined by 
$$
F(x) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2\left( \varphi_n(x)-(n+1)(n+2)x^2 \psi_n(x) \right)x^{n+1} \, ,
$$
where $x \in [0,1)$. 
The function series $\varphi_n$ and $\psi_n$ respectively read
$$
\varphi_n (x) = \frac{\lambda n^2(n+1)(n+3)(n+2)^2 \left( {(2n+1)}{x^{n+3}} - {(2n+5)}{x^{n+1}} \right)}
 {4\lambda n^6+36\lambda n^5+118\lambda n^4+(168\lambda+16)n^3+(94\lambda+72)n^2+(12\lambda+92)n+30}
$$
and 
$$
\psi_n(x) = -\frac{\varphi_{n+2} (x)}{4n+10} + \frac{1}{S_n}
  \bigg(
  \frac{G_n}{2n+1} \varphi_n(x) 
  +\lambda n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\bigg( \frac{x^{n+1}}{2n+1} - \frac{x^{n+3}}{2n+5} \bigg) \bigg)
$$
where $\lambda$ is a pure imaginary complex number and
 \begin{align}
  S_n &:= 2\left( \lambda n^4+6\lambda n^3+(11\lambda+4)n^2+(6\lambda+16)n+15 \right) \, , \\
  G_n &:= \lambda n^4+6\lambda n^3+(11\lambda+4)n^2+(6\lambda+8)n+3 \, .
 \end{align}

My goal is to find a closed mathematical form of the function
$$
f(x) := \lim_{\lambda\to\infty} F (x)
$$

For this aim, I have tried to pass the limit through the infinite sum, and compute the infinite sum as a next step. 
It turns out that this approach leads to erroneous results, when comparing with numerical examples.
I was wondering whether such series could be analytically evaluated.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

a

Comment: Have you tried a first order expansion in $1/\lambda$? It's hard to read the coefficients but it looks like the resulting expansion will converge (in $n$).

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks for your quick reply. I will give it a try now.